# Find and replace

Tags: excel, filter, find-replace, vba

i want to write a formula to do the following either in macro or conditional formatting

Cells A & B both have Values

i want to say:

if B=Yes, then replace the existing text in column A to Yes, and leave the other values in column A as is.

[image]

Comment: Please understand that Stack Overflow is no free code writing service. Therefore please [edit] your question and add the code you already have, or show what research you did to achieve your goal. Taking a [Tour] and reading [ask] might help to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
For i=0 To Worksheets("sheet 1").Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    
    If Worksheets("sheet 1").Range("B" & i). Value = "Yes" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet").Range("A" & i).Value = "Yes"
    End If
End For
```

Comment: That formula did not work. i wrote this but it is still not replacing.Sub Vendor()
        
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 5 To Worksheets("Modernization").Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, "CP").Text = "Synergy" Then
    Cells(i, "CO").Text = "Synergy"
    End If
    Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
 
 
    
End Sub

Comment: @Rodrigo While this might help the OP, it is a bad practice to post code only answers without explaining anything. So it is always a good idea to provide some context so even further readers can learn from it. • Btw. starting row counting with `0` cannot work because Excel always starts with row `1`.

Comment: @sara As you can see code in comments is pretty unreadable. Therefore please always include the code in your original question.